# Putty can connect to server but client cannot

Tags: c#, sockets, server, client, putty

I have a command line application that listens on an address ie. 192.168.1.89:8001. I also have a c# client application that uses a socket to communicate with the server. Both of these applications are running on the same machine and I am not able connect to the server.

When I try to input 192.168.1.89:8001 as the address for the client I get a "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" error. However when I used putty to make a raw connection to that same address I was successfully able to communicate with the server. Any ideas why putty is able to connect but not the client?

The client is creating the socket like this
`this.socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);`
`socket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(HostIP), Port);`.

Comment: Which class type is `socket` ?  Is it a generic `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` or a `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` or something else?

Comment: I am using the System.Net.Sockets.Socket

Comment: Show what parameters you pass to the socket constructor.  Does the command-line application loop and continue listening, or does it accept only one connection and then close its listener?  You might have to relaunch it between connecting with PuTTY and trying to connect with your C# program.  Use `netstat -a` to make sure the program is still listening on the expected port.

Comment: The command line application only accepts one connection. I always restart the server between attempts to connect. In the case where the server is listening at 192.168.1.89:8001 I call the constructor like this `socket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.89"), "8001");`

Comment: That's not a constructor.  You probably have a line of code somewhere looking like `socket = new Socket(...)`

Comment: Sorry here is the constructor `this.socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);`

Comment: Ok, those are the correct constructor parameters.  Does it still fail if you temporarily turn off Windows Firewall?

Comment: The connection still failed when I disabled windows firewall.